# Custom Form for Document send to option

Tags: custom-form

I have a project on Sharepoint 2010 which requires the following:

1) Under the document settings, there is a "send to" option, I need to be able to add a location to that "send to" which will access a custom form. (Thinking ASP form?) but the question will be how to add that form to the options.

2) This custom form must be able to display the file structure of another site collection's document centre (There are about 19 document libraries in that site collection) and the user will be allowed to select the location to add that document to.

I'm thinking something like reading through the site collection's document libraries and building a file structure from there. (Will this work? worried about performance as it has to read every time the form loads)

3) After confirming the location, it will direct the user straight to the submit document form (Sharepoint 2010 OOB) of that folder.

I'm hoping there's a certain URL I can pass through that will link it straight there or at least pass a string value that accesses the folder.